# Conditional Insert using T-SQL on each row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two main tables

1. Postion
2. geography

If the row in `position` intersects the row in `geography`, I need to insert it in third table.

But the problem is I have to check the existing row in the third table and then insert it.

I can do this with set operations,but the problem is I can't process each row (i.e. if there are two rows with similar data,need to insert only the first).

I can do with cursor but I read its a bad thing.

Can anyone help me to process each row before inserting?

Comment: You should use a [merge](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) statement with a proper ON clause to insert data into your third table.

Answer (score 3):

At first put all you need in CTE with [ROW_NUMBER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) to get only 1 row for each ID. Then [MERGE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx):

```
;WITH cte AS (
SELECT  g.*,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTTION BY SomeColumn ORDER BY SomeColumn) as rn
FROM Postion p
INNER JOIN geography g
    ON p.someID = g.SomeID
)

MERGE ThirdTable as target
USING (SELECT * FROM cte WHERE rn = 1) as source
ON target.SomeID = source.SomeID
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
    INSERT (target fields)
    VALUES (source values);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help,the solution was nice,I tried using it but it was not fitting my use case.Also I needed to insert on match as well.I ended up using cursor.

Answer (score 0):

// #temp contains all the required field from intersection of position and geography and will check it with third table using left join

```
select p.* into #temp
from position p inner join geography g
on p.id = g.id


insert into thirdtable
select * from #temp t1 left join thirdtable t2
on t1.id = t2.id
where t2.id is null
```